# How to use Eclipse Transformer to update a Spring Boot 3 project's "javax" dependency to use "jakarta" imports?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm working on a Java Spring Boot project that uses `io.katharsis.katharsis-spring` as a dependency. When I attempt to compile/build my project with `mvn clean install -fae`, I get the following errors. These show up for a specific sub-module of my project, which has its own pom.xml.

```
[ERROR] /…/katharis/CustomKatharsisConfigV3.java:[74,34] cannot access javax.servlet.Filter
  class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found
[ERROR]  /…/katharis/CustomKatharsisConfigV3.java:[75,32] type argument io.katharsis.spring.KatharsisFilterV2 is not within bounds of type-variable T
[ERROR]  /…/katharis/CustomKatharsisConfigV3.java:[75,84] incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean<>
    reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
      equality constraints: io.katharsis.spring.KatharsisFilterV2
      lower bounds: jakarta.servlet.Filter
```

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the `io.katharsis.spring.KatharsisFilterV2` class in question. And that project hasn't been updated since 2017!

At first, I tried to switch from `katharsis` to `crnk`, its successor. However, I ran into the same `javax` vs `jakarta` issue: https://github.com/crnk-project/crnk-framework/issues/869 (issue opened in December 2022).

Ultimately, I'd like to contribute to the `crnk` project and see it updated. However, for now, I'm stuck with figuring out how to use my `katharsis` dependency (with its `javax` imports) in my Spring Boot 3.1.4 project (which is requiring `jakarta` imports).

I've been trying to use Eclipse Transformer (https://github.com/eclipse/transformer) for this. And, when using the Transformer CLI to manually adjust the `katharsis` .jar in my local .m2 directory, it works!

However, I'm at a loss for whether/how to use Eclipse Transformer in my CI/CD pipeline. I'm trying to use the transformer-maven-plugin (https://github.com/eclipse/transformer/tree/main/maven-plugins/transformer-maven-plugin), but haven't had any luck yet.

Here's my current transformer-maven-plugin configuration in the pom.xml for the sub-module in question (an "api-starter").

```
<build>  
    <plugins>  
       <plugin>  
          <groupId>org.eclipse.transformer</groupId>  
          <artifactId>transformer-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
          <extensions>true</extensions>  
          <configuration>  
             <rules>  
                <jakartaDefaults>true</jakartaDefaults>  
             </rules>  
          </configuration>  
          <executions>  
             <execution>  
                <id>default-jar</id>  
                <goals>  
                   <goal>jar</goal>  
                </goals>  
                <configuration>  
                   <artifact>  
                      <groupId>io.katharsis</groupId>  
                      <artifactId>katharsis-spring</artifactId>  
                      <version>2.8.2</version>  
                   </artifact>  
                </configuration>  
             </execution>  
             <execution>  
                <id>javadoc-jar</id>  
                <goals>  
                   <goal>jar</goal>  
                </goals>  
                <configuration>  
                   <artifact>  
                      <groupId>io.katharsis</groupId>  
                      <artifactId>katharsis-spring</artifactId>  
                      <version>2.8.2</version>  
                      <classifier>javadoc</classifier>  
                   </artifact>  
                </configuration>  
             </execution>  
             <execution>  
                <id>source-jar</id>  
                <goals>  
                   <goal>jar</goal>  
                </goals>  
                <configuration>  
                   <artifact>  
                      <groupId>io.katharsis</groupId>  
                      <artifactId>katharsis-spring</artifactId>  
                      <version>2.8.2</version>  
                      <classifier>sources</classifier>  
                   </artifact>  
                </configuration>  
             </execution>  
          </executions>  
       </plugin>  
    </plugins>  
</build>
```

Perhaps its because I haven't situated the plugin's work correctly in the context of maven's lifecycle? I've tried putting the plugin configuration code at various pom.xml levels in my three-tiered project (parent pom, module pom, sub-module pom), but still get the same compilation errors noted above.

Is there a small change I need to make to my use of the transformer-maven-plugin? Is the maven plugin the right way to use Eclipse Transformer for something like this? Is there another tool/method/solution entirely that I should consider?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try using a different name instead of `default-jar` and adding `<phase>validate</phase>` or `<phase>compile</phase>` to the execution?